# Paraview: Merge Multiple .stl and save as single (.stl)

Tags: visualization, paraview, finite-element-analysis

How could I merge multiple (.stls) and save as a single (.stl) file?

I would like to save all the (.stls) in the following as a single (.stl) file in Paraview.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the STL sources and run **Filters** -> **Append Datasets**. Save the result.

Comment: Is it possible to separate these objects again when they are stored as an unstructured grid?

Comment: Not in general. If each STL file contains geometry that is a separate connected component, you could isolate each component with the **Connectivity** filter followed by a **Threshold** filter.

Alternatively, you could run the **Group Datasets** filter on the STL files, forming a multiblock data set. Each block can then be extracted with the **Extract Block** filter, then this can be converted to a `vtkPolyData` with a succession of **Merge Blocks** and **Extract Surface** filters.

Comment: The .stl file type is missing from the Save Data menu after appending several stl meshes, so this dowsn't work unfortunately.